# Add style using REST

Tags: geoserver

I have many *.sld styles which I want to add/import to GeoServer and then apply to imported layers.

I can apply an existing style with:

```
curl -u admin:password -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<layer><defaultStyle><name>thestylename</name></defaultStyle><enabled>true</enabled></layer>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/workspace:layer
```

But how can I import a style file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/index.html) is the place to look for these things - see the [REST styles page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/styles.html#creating-a-style)

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @roads_style.zip http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles
```